# How to keep UIViews from touching

Tags: ios, swift

So I have a main Imageview in the center of my screen and 150 x 150, I programmatically creating views with a random x and y value as well as a random width/height (these are the same value). I want the views to surround the main imageview but not to touch it. Also on the y axis I have a tabbar that has of the self.view.frame and a height of 35 which I also don't want these views to touch. Any ideas?

Comment: are the created views allowed to overlap?

Comment: I'd rather they not, but it might be kind of hard to avoid it since it's random

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you randomize polar coordinates (angle and radius, with the reference being the center of your image view) instead of cartesian coordinates (x and y)? It'll be easier to control the distance from the center if you have angles and radiuses. You can increase the radius depending on what your random width and height ends up being so it's further from the center to compensate and avoid collisions.

```
let centerImageView = UIImageView()

//..

//Bounding circle for the image view
let centerRadius = max(centerImageView.width, centerImageView.height)

func randomFloat(min: Float, max: Float) {
    return min + (max - min) * (arc4random() / RAND_MAX)
}

//Somewhere else in your loop for generating views

let angle = randomFloat(0, Float.pi * 2)
//Dimensions of the random view
let width = randomFloat(min: 10, max: 50)
let height = randomFloat(min: 10, max: 50)
//Bounding circle, you can use an ellipse, or calculate the distance perfectly for that angle too, but this is simpler
let viewRadius = randomFloat(min: width, max: height)
//The distance from the center must be greater than the sum of both bounding circles' radiuses, plus some
let radius = centerRadius + viewRadius + randomFloat(min: 50, max: 100)
//Convert to cartesian coordinates
let x = centerImageView.center.x + cos(angle) * radius
let y = centerImageView.center.y + sin(angle) * radius

let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: height)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Unfortunately that didn't work for me, but how could you use something similar to this to wrap the pictures around the centerImageView?

Comment: there was a lot of casting and the final result didn't display and views on screen

Comment: Did you actually try to understand what I did rather than just pasting it in there?

Comment: the only thing i dont understand is the viewRadius, what does that do?

Comment: Please observe my awesome paint drawing skills in the edited response. viewRadius is the bounding circle of the random view you're creating. The yellow line represents the "radius" var in the code. Since the minimum value it takes is viewRadius + centerRadius + (whatever you use for min in the random), the bounding circles never touch.

Answer (score 0):

```
func intersects(_ rect2: CGRect) -> Bool
```

If your center view intersect with newly created view then randomly generate new frame.